# SSIS C# - Extract CSV from CDATA with Commas

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, csv, ssis

We have an SSIS package that issues a REST API call as an XML document and receives the response as  an XML document.  We're using RestSharp in an SSIS Script Component (within a Data Flow Task) to send the request and return the data.  This part is working correctly.

Where we're running into issues is that the return XML stores the data that we need as CSV within the CDATA part of the XML response.  Despite the data being wrapped within double-quotes in the CSV, the part of our code that is designed to split this apart and assign it to the output columns is incorrectly splitting some values due to commas in the data, despite being double-quoted.

This is the current code that I'm attempting to use to parse the CSV into columns, which are then sent to the output of the Script Component and on to the destination table in SQL Server:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(response.Content);

var string1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("response").InnerText;

string[] splitStart = string1.Split('\n');

int counter1;
int counter2;

for (counter1 = 0; counter1 < splitStart.Length; counter1++)
{
  string[] splitEnd = splitStart[counter1].Split(',');
  counter2 = 0;

  MMABuffer.AddRow();
  MMABuffer.Col01 = splitStart[counter1];
  MMABuffer.Col02 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col03 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col04 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col05 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col06 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col07 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col08 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col09 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col10 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col11 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col12 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col13 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col14 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col15 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col16 = splitEnd[counter2]; counter2++;
  MMABuffer.Col17 = splitEnd[counter2];

}
```

The input - the value of `string1` looks like this:

```
"Col01","Col02","Col03","Col04","Col05","Col06","Col07","Col08","Col09","Col10","Col11","Col12","Col13","Col14","Col15","Col16"
"S736243","StackOverflow","900780","Blah Blarg,ePTFE Graft,standardwall, reinforced,l: 80cm, d: 8mm","102010","FE","ePTFE","6790","","FG","Blah Graft","Standard Blah Grafts","Other Blah/Grafts","ePTFE","HCH",""
"S736244","StackOverflow","900782","Blah Blarg,ePTFE Graft,thinwall, reinforced,l: 10cm, d: 5mm","102010","FE","ePTFE","6790","","FG","Blah Graft","Standard Blah Grafts","Other Blah/Grafts","ePTFE","HCH",""
"S736245","StackOverflow","900783","Blah Blarg,ePTFE Graft,thinwall, reinforced,l:40cm, d: 5mm","102010","FE","ePTFE","6790","","FG","Blah Graft","Standard Blah Grafts","Other Blah/Grafts","ePTFE","HCH",""
"S736246","StackOverflow","900784","Blah Blarg,ePTFE Graft,thinwall, reinforced,l: 70cm, d: 5mm","102010","FE","ePTFE","6790","","FG","Blah Graft","Standard Blah Grafts","Other Blah/Grafts","ePTFE","HCH",""
"S736291","StackOverflow","901401","E-vita Blarg 3GØprox: 40mmØdist: 36mmLcovered: 170mm","201010","FE","E-vita Blarg 3G","6720","","FG","Blarg Grafts","Standard Blarg Grafts","Blarg Grafts","Blarg","HCH",""
"S736292","StackOverflow","901402","E-vita Blarg 3GØprox: 40mmØdist: 40mmLcovered: 170mm","201010","FE","E-vita Blarg 3G","6720","","FG","Blarg Grafts","Standard Blarg Grafts","Blarg Grafts","Blarg","HCH",""
"S736293","StackOverflow","901403","E-vita Blarg 3GØprox: 44mmØdist: 40mmLcovered: 170mm","201010","FE","E-vita Blarg 3G","6720","","FG","Blarg Grafts","Standard Blarg Grafts","Blarg Grafts","Blarg","HCH",""
"S736294","StackOverflow","901406","E-vita Blarg 3GØprox: 40mmØdist: 36mmLcovered: 130mm","201010","FE","E-vita Blarg 3G","6720","","FG","Blarg Grafts","Standard Blarg Grafts","Blarg Grafts","Blarg","HCH",""
```

The first four lines do not import correctly with the code above, due to the presence of the ',' in the `Col04` value - despite the value being double-quoted.

The last four lines do import correctly, as there is no ',' in the `Col04` value.

I'm certain that the issue lies within how I am splitting the input in the `for {}` block above, but I am not sure how to correct it.  I based this code off of another API call package, however that data does not have any ',' within it's input, so this issue isn't encountered.

Comment: Have you already considered using [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=net-7.0)? Since your column is properly quoted text, it should be able to handle this.

Comment: @Filburt - I'm not sure that I can, because this is an SSIS Script Component, and I have to be able to assign values to the pre-configured output columns (the part with the MMABuffer).

Comment: TextFieldParser just can take the job of splitting up your `string1` and you'll still be able to pump rows into your output buffer. The only additional step will be to create a (memory)stream of your `string1`.

Comment: @Filburt - I actually just tried using TextFieldParser and figured out how to assign the columns to the output buffer.  But I think there's something wrong with my implementation because I get a "System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path." the problem being that I can't tell where, as SSIS doesn't allow me to debug script components that I know of.

Comment: You simply put a breakpoint into your Script Component code and it will jump in and debug. I'm preparing an answer - just took me some time to fire up the dev machine with SSDT installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script component, add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` - this is required to use `TextFieldParser`.

```cs
using System.IO // required for MemoryStream
using System.Text // required for Encoding.UTF8
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

public override void CreateNewOutputRows
{
    // your code extrating the CDATA string

    // create a MemoryStream from your string1 bytes and fallback to empty string just in case
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string1 ?? "")))
    {
        // create a parser on your stream
        using(var parser = new TextFieldParser(ms))
        {
            // set the field delimiter(s)
            parser.Delimiter = new string[] { "," };

            // your CSV has text in quotes
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            // to skip the column header row, just read the line before starting to iterate.
            parser.ReadLine();

            while(!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                // get all fields from the current line
                string[] currentrow = parser.ReadFields();

                // ... and add to your output buffer
                MMABuffer.AddRow();

                MMABuffer.Col01 = currentrow[0];
                MMABuffer.Col02 = currentrow[1];
                // ... etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to adjust the encoding for creating the MemoryStream depending on the encoding of the API response.

To inspect the values that are read, put a breakpoint in your Script Component and step through your code with F10. Hover over `currentrow` to see the array of fields and their values.

Comment: Converting the `string1` to a Stream was the part I was missing - this works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

use back ticks `` instead of "".

Comment: I don't follow? The format of the data from the XML CDATA block is fixed from the API vendor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).